# CKEditor doesn't take config.js

Tags: javascript, configuration, ckeditor

[CKEDITOR 4 Documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_configuration)

The CKEditor documentation says:

> CKEditor comes with a rich set of configuration options that make it
>   possible to customize its appearance, features, and behavior. The main
>   configuration file is named `config.js`. This file can be found in the
>   root of the CKEditor installation folder.

However I change something in `config.js` and no change nothing, I am doing something bad ?

Comment: Could you attach your `config.js` file and show us changes which you have made?

Comment: I ran `bower install ckeditor`, it created a `bower_components`  folder, inside it is `ckeditor` folder with the `config.js` file, details config.js http://i.prntscr.com/8Xm0PCp2RW6jbFR2djxhjw.png

Comment: Bower should not have any influence on `config.js` and configuration should work as expected. Could you perhaps try adding more noticeable configuration setting like - 
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-uiColor and clearing browser's cache according to: https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache

Comment: @jjoselon im also facing the same issue any solution ??